# Show fields (consider 500 field or more) based on values of 3 different picklist fields

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, aura, lightning-design-system

I have 3 picklist: P1, P2, P3

I want to show others fields on Lightning page based on the values selected on P1,P2,P3.

Example:

```
P1 has values as : P1V1, P1V2
P2 has values as : P2V1, P2V2
P3 has values as : P3V1, P3V2
```

I want to show 100 fields when P1V1 is selected in P1 and P2V1 is selected in P2 and P3V1 is selected in P3.

Where i can store mapping this much data : Custom metadata or Custom Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Metadata can be used to solve this problem. Also, you can use custommetadataloader to load data instead of creating manually.
https://github.com/forcedotcom/CustomMetadataLoader